# Simple Rails 3 Query not loading data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue where records are not returning from the database. No errors are thrown but perhaps I'm missing something simple. I set my database yml for development, test and production to the same thing just to make sure I was targeting the database in question.

Querying directly from the database returns 3 institutions.

**Model - institution.rb**

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :childinstitutions, :class_name => "Institution",
      :foreign_key => "parentinstitution_id"
  belongs_to :parentinstitution, :class_name => "Institution"

  def self.search(term)
    if term
      Institution.where('institutionname LIKE ?', :term).all
    else
      Institution.all
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller - institutions_controller.rb**

```
class InstitutionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @institutions = Institution.search(params[:term])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @institutions }
    end
  end

  def show
    @institution = Institution.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @institution }
    end
  end

  def new
    @institution = Institution.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @institution }
    end
  end
end
```

**View - institutions/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing Institutions</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th><% @institutions.length %> records</th>
  </tr>

<% for institution in @institutions %>
  <tr>
    <td><% institution.id %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```

**Result**
A really big **Listing Institutions** and Id records on the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this a few times now, and in case anyone ever comes across a similar issue, my issue had to deal with the **View portion**. Seriously a case of the RTFM, here. Referenced fields to display to screen should have <%= instead of <%.

**Updated View**

```
<h1>Listing Institutions</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th></th>
    <th><%= @institutions.length %> records</th>
  </tr>

<% for institution in @institutions %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= institution.id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```